# NSSlider popover

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsslider

I have a custom `NSSlider`.

Because of lacking space I want to show the value of it only when the user hovers over the slider.
Just like this one:
http://dribbble.com/shots/754412-Range-Selection

I know how the hover part works, using `NSTrackingArea`.
My question is, how would I correctly make a popover like this?

I've had this question for quite a while.
I guess you would use the same technique for animating single small elements over the screen outside of a window.

Comment: I expect it's similar to a tooltip--you create and position a new NSWindow that contains the content of your hovering indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `NSWindow`. Make it borderless and non-opaque so you can define its shape through a background image. [Convert coordinates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW56) so you can position the "popover" window relative to the slider. Make it a [child](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW37) of the window containing the slider so that weird stuff doesn't happen with the Window menu, Exposé/Mission Control, etc.